# Getting Vine Top User List

Tags: vine

I want to get vine top user list.
I tried to search all actions in Vine API but didn't find action relative to user list.
How can I do that?
Regards me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get the complete list of Vine users, so you have to write a kind of crawler that will explore the social network graph (with users as nodes and relationships 'follows/followed by' as edges) and collect users to your database. After doing that just sort the results by number of followers. Info about users and relationships are available via [API](https://github.com/starlock/vino/wiki/API-Reference), have fun.